# How to display URL in Error message in User Standard object using Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages

I have tried all the ways still its not working. Can you please help....

Trigger:

```
trigger UserDelegatedApproverExpiration on User (before update){

    for(User u: Trigger.new)
    {
       String ecUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/delegatedUser?id='+u.id;
       String ecMsg = '<a style=\'color:1B2BE8\' target="_blank" href="'+ecUrl+'"> Here </a>';

         if(u.DelegatedApproverId != null){
            if(u.Delegated_Approver_Expiration_Date__c == null && u.Delegated_Approver_Start_Date__c == null){
             u.addError('<br/>Please enter Delegated Approver from '+ ecMsg +' <br>', True);
        }
      }       
    }
 }
```

Error :

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
<br/>Please enter Delegated Approver from <a style='color:1B2BE8' target="_blank" href="https://cs26.salesforce.com/apex/delegatedUser?id=00560000002OwWGAA0"> Here </a> <br>
```

Comment: Markup has no place in a trigger context. Think about how that would look from data loader. This sort of error message should be added from your controller instead, if you are on a page.

Comment: This error message is displaying on User Object(Standard) record. Want to display with the link...

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is with this line:

```
u.addError('<br/>Please enter Delegated Approver from '+ ecMsg +' <br>', True);
```

The second argument needs to be `false` if you want the HTML link to appear

```
u.addError('<br/>Please enter Delegated Approver from '+ ecMsg +' <br>', false);
```

*from a sample of code I wrote*

```
foo.addError('blah ' + 
             '<a href="' +
             URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+
             '/' + someId +
             '">' +
             somefriendlyTextForLink +
             '</a>',
             false);
```

Comment: Its not possible to display URL error message in USER object. We already contacted SFDC Team. Thank you!